# NoClassDefFoundError in onStart method - Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing Amazon IAP into my Media player app. I have registered my observer as it was said in Amazon docs. But, when I ran the project it is throwing `NoClassDefFoundError`.

There is no compilation error in the project and the class is right there in the project with correct package name. Searched other forums but not able to solve the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.songs.mysongs.PlaySongObserver
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at com.songs.mysongs.PlaySongActivity.onStart(PlaySongActivity.java:111)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4639)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1972)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4479)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-08 21:02:07.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It seems apk missing some of the required jar files. Make sure all required jars are inside lib folder.

Comment: My android build version is 4.0.3 and min sdk version is 2.3.3. It is there and I have added amazon iap jar file as well.

Comment: I would give a try by including that jar.

Comment: @Nambari: which jar you are saying? amazon iap jar?, I have added that.

Comment: @Nambari: I have created libs folder in my project and added iap jar explicitly. It worked after that. However, It didn't worked if i added jar through build path(add external jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.If you are using new `SDK` there is quite different way of adding library in the project.

1. Create folder named as `libs` in your project and place your library over there.
2. Right click on your project > Build Path > Add External Archives

I hope this will resolve your issue.If you have already added the library by using add external library then try to follow the steps which I mention.

Comment: I have added my amazon iap jar and Android 4.0.3 jar file in libs folder. Clean and re-compiled. still same issue. Strangely, this is working for the sample app given by Amazon. My code doesn't have any difference than their code. :(

Comment: I didn't clean the project after adding in libs folder. It is working like a charm now. Many thanks Akshay. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

After adding jar check it to be exported to.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project has resolved NoClassDefFoundError with the purchasing observer in my case; I guess .jar libraries are not always picked up automatically?